# How i can apply alertDialog as server response in AsyncTask

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to connect my project `app` with an online database through `cPanel` Hosting. I used the `AlertDialog.Builder`, `setOnClickListener`,
for showing the response of the server but it seems i got some error any answers will be appreciated Thanks

here is my java file.

```
//Calling my AsyncTask
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 view.setEnabled(false);
 Intent launchactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(launchactivity);

            tvscancontent = tvScanContent.getText().toString();
            tvscanformat = tvScanFormat.getText().toString();
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
            backgroundTask.execute(tvscancontent,tvscanformat);
            finish();

            showShowView2();
           // displaynotification();

        }

    });

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> { // i got crash here

        Context context;
        String add_info_url;
        private Object activity;




        public BackgroundTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


            add_info_url = "http://www.d48.asia/shan/index.php";

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String tvscancontent = args[0];
            String tvscanformat = args[1];
            String response = "";
            String line = "";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("tvscancontent", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tvscancontent, "UTF-8")+ "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("tvscanformat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tvscanformat, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                    response+= line;


                }


                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return response;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

     //Server response
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            //Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER ,0,0);
            //toast.show();
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); // also i got crash here
                    alert.setTitle("Third Wheel Response");
                    alert.setMessage(result);
                    alert.setCancelable(false);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                          dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialogs = alert.create();
                    dialogs.show();


                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    SaveData.setEnabled(true);

                }
```

ERRORS:

11-10 08:40:23.174 4815-4815/com.thethirdwheelproject.thirdwheel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.thethirdwheelproject.thirdwheel, PID: 4815
                                                                                   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@bc0afcf is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:678)
                                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
                                                                                       at com.thethirdwheelproject.thirdwheel.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:489)
                                                                                       at com.thethirdwheelproject.thirdwheel.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:389)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-10 08:40:23.733 1334-1334/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1334: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Your context variable is null !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your context variable is not initialized

Remove your `context` variable and use instead `MainActivity.this`.

Try this way

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 view.setEnabled(false);
            tvscancontent = tvScanContent.getText().toString();
            tvscanformat = tvScanFormat.getText().toString();
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
            backgroundTask.execute(tvscancontent,tvscanformat);
            showShowView2();
           // displaynotification();

        }

    });
```

Comment: i still got this error sir 

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> // i got crash here

dialogs.show(); //also here

Comment: How to call BackgroundTask class?

Comment: @ShanMichaelReyes I run your code it's working fine !! How to call Your AsyncTask ?

Comment: take a look of my update post sir i already post on how i call my AsyncTask wish you can help me thank you sir

Comment: Why are you finish() activity after calling BackgroundTask?

Comment: it works now sir thankyou thankyou thankyou godbless you sir :)

Comment: done it sorry im just newbie in stackoverflaw thanks again sir

Comment: on the left side of answer you can see the Up/Down Arrow so others can get idea of this. Use Up arrow to appreciate the answer. Ans check mark icon to accept .

Answer (score 0):

set the context in your constructor, 
something like below

```
public BackgroundTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: how did you pass context to your AsyncTask class?

Comment: i just assign context variable in my AsyncTask class sir

Comment: But I changed context to MainActivity.this, the code is worked. so you may have other error caused that situation. post your error log and the code how you execute your asynctask class.

Comment: android.os.BinderProxy@bc0afcf is not valid; is your activity running? 

MainActivity is finished???
you may inspect your code how and when you call your asynctask, or do you finish MainActivity when asynctask is called?

Comment: take a look of my update post sir i already post on how i call my AsyncTask wish you can help me thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Calling my AsyncTask
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setEnabled(false);

            tvscancontent = tvScanContent.getText().toString();
            tvscanformat = tvScanFormat.getText().toString();
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask =new BackgroundTask();
            backgroundTask.execute(tvscancontent,tvscanformat);

            showShowView2();
           // displaynotification();

        }

    });
```

//inserting data into database process
    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    String add_info_url;


    public BackgroundTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        add_info_url = "http://www.d48.asia/shan/index.php";

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Authentication Process");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String tvscancontent = args[0];
        String tvscanformat = args[1];
        String response = "";
        String line = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("tvscancontent", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tvscancontent, "UTF-8")+ "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("tvscanformat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tvscanformat, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle(" Third Wheel Response");
                alert.setMessage(result);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setPositiveButton("Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent launchactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(launchactivity);


                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialogs = alert.create();
                dialogs.show();

            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                SaveData.setEnabled(true);

            }


    }
```